# Iframe FancyBox 2.1.4 in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, iframe, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have problems with the Firefox. It opens a FancyBox but no with the original dimensions. Please Can you help me?.

*moved from comments* :

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">
        <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="luscoefusco13.es/index2.html"><img src="luscoefusco13.es/imaxes/intro/intro_04.gif"; alt="" name="intro" width="385" height="18" title="Entrar"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox, iframe').fancybox();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox, iframe').fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        'padding': 0,
        'autoSize': false,
        'width': 718,
        'height': 503
    });
});
```

Comment: please show some code

Comment: I am using FancyBox 2.1.4.

Comment: @BraisRemeseiro, edit your question if you are adding necessary details rather than posting it as comments.

Comment: Please, Can you answer?.

Comment: @BraisRemeseiro : if you mean that you cannot get the size of 718x503 set `fitToView` to `false` and change this `$('.fancybox, iframe')` by this `$('.fancybox')`

Comment: <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.fancybox').fancybox();
  });
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
    type: 'iframe',
    'padding' : 0,  
    'fitToView': false,
 'autoSize': false,      
    'width': 718, 
    'height': 503
     });
});
    </script>                                                              Is fine this code?. It does not function. What should I do JFK?.

Answer (score 0):

you just need this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        type: "iframe",
        padding: 0,
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: false,
        width: 718,
        height: 503
    });
});
</script>
```

Of course, you should have an html like this

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://domain.com/page.html">open iframe</a>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uzGqe/1/)**

Comment: Hi JFK, first of all thanks for replying. I did it with the code and in Firefox it appears reduced. What should I do?.

Comment: Please, Can you answer?. I still have problems with the width and the height in Firefox.

Comment: @BraisRemeseiro : does the jsfiddle work fine? can you share a link?

Comment: Hi, thanks again. Yes the jsfiddle works fine. In Safari I see perfect the FancyBox but in Firefox appeared a bit reduced with scrollbars in the width/height. What do you mean a link to share?, An URL of th website?. I upload the index.html with the FancyBox iframe modification. The web is: luscoefusco13.es. You can enter the website by pressing the "entrar" button. If you can see the code I also would like to ask you if the main table is fine centered at the middle of the screen, and If you can fix the "entrar" button that shows highlighted in the Dreamweaver. Thanks mate.

Comment: Please, Can you answer?.

Comment: @BraisRemeseiro : maybe you also need to add the option `scrolling: "no"`

Comment: Also, How Can I modify the Flash contents of the website using FancyBox iframe?.

Comment: JFK moe or less now I solved...However when I open a section of the web suddenly appear two pop-ups. Please, Can you help me?.